# USE statement permission on Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I know that `USE` for switching databases isn't supported on Azure SQL. However, generally, if I'm in the `dbexample` database then `USE [dbexample];` runs successfully without issue.

However, a colleague was given access to an Azure SQL db by someone else with their AAD credentials.

On the master database they can run `USE [master];` without issue.

On the actual database (`dbexample`) they cannot run `USE [dbexample]`. Why can't they do this?!?

Is this a permission issue or something related to AAD? In ever other Azure SQL database I've had access too, I've always had the `db_owner` role.

Answer (score 1):

we can run `USE current_database` satatements in current database, but we can't use `USE other_database` to access other database in Azure SQL database.

Master DB:

[image]

User DB:
[image]

For example, if you run `use dbexample` in other database or master DB, you will always get this error:

```
Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
```

[image]

Cross data database query is different with on-premise SQL Server. No matter you use normal database user or AAD user. These have nothing to do with the user permission.

Ref here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. what I'm saying is a colleague is getting an error when running `use dbexample` while in the `dbexample` database. what's up with that??

Comment: @AndersSwanson We don't know. Only if your colleague give us more details,  or we can't help more.  Usually, the error wouldn't happen.

Comment: Hi @AndersSwanson, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Did you answer my question?

Comment: @AndersSwanson The key is can you repeat the error? As I said the error wouldn't happen. If you believe that and want to solve it, please let your colleague show the screenshots for us.  You also can let him try again to ensure you  see the error happen again.